# dynamically add an element within a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to let the user add a form element if they want to add a utensil using Jquery, i am really stuck and can't see how to do this. Could anyone help?

Thank you!

```
<form id="recipe_form" name ="recipe_form" action="createxml.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
          <h1> Recipe Name</h1>


        <h1> Preperation Time + Description</h1>
        <label for="prep_time">Enter Preparation Time</label>
        <input type="text" name="prep_time" ><br />

        <label for="descrip">Enter a recipe Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="descrip" ><br />
        <br />

        <div id="utensil">

        <h1> Untensils </h1>
        <label for="utensil_num">Enter Utensil number</label>
        <input type="text" name="utensil_num"><br />

        <label for="utensil_descrip">Enter Utensil Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="utensil_descrip">
            <a href="#" id"addRow"> Add Another Utensil </a><br />

        </div>


        <br />
        <button type="submit">Save on xml</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it using a button click

```
jQuery("#buttonid").click(function(){
jQuery( "#utensil" ).append( "<input type=\"text\">" ); 



})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: great thank you, is it possible to add it to a specific part of my form? say the utensil bit?

Comment: sorry for another question but would what i piut for the onclick=  on the button?

Comment: Yes its the same, I have edited the answer for you so you can put it inside the utensil section.

Comment: thank you, just tried it apparently i'm missing a semi colon here though

jQuery("#buttonid").click(function(){

Comment: got it working thank you! is there a function to remove one as well?

Comment: @NickPocock Yes Nick, it will be the same click function but instead of append, use remove i.e (jQuery("#The ID of the ELEMENT YOU NEED TO REMOVE").remove();)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jQuery.html()` method at your convenience

```
jQuery('#recipe_form').html("<input type=\"text\">")
```

this will insert an input element inside your form, trigger the event to insert the html whenever is convenient for you

Comment: is that possible to do through a button click

Comment: Sure it is. 
jQuery('#button').click(function(){
      jQuery('#recipe_form').html("<input type=\"text\">") 
});

Comment: Can you see where i'm going wrong? www.jsfiddle.net/nzYAW/

Comment: Seems to work fine what's the problem?